# RuntimeException: API key not found. Check that geo.API_KEY is in the AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

I am attempting to compile a simple map display on my my phone, but the app keeps closing.  It seems that all my ducks are in a row, but I'm just stumped.  This is my first time working with an API in Android Studio

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.morticia.android.firstmap">

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.morticia.android.maptest_app"
        android:value="AIzaSyBf3tEmdR18S-2v0E1i1x0oqcXJ9imntT4" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

And this is my MainActivity XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    map:cameraBearing="112.5"
    map:cameraTargetLat="40.7484"
    map:cameraTargetLng="-73.9857"
    map:cameraTilt="65"
    map:cameraZoom="17" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally MainActivity Java code:

```
package com.morticia.android.firstmap;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

here are the logs as requested:

```
02-02 20:29:13.420 26932-26932/com.morticia.android.firstmap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.morticia.android.firstmap, PID: 26932
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.morticia.android.firstmap/com.morticia.android.firstmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                                                                               at com.morticia.android.firstmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                                                                               at com.morticia.android.firstmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
                                                                               at maps.y.k.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at maps.v.c.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at xg.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:62)
                                                                               at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                               at trn.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:179)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:99)
                                                                               at trm.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:62)
                                                                               at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzt(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zzwP(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at android.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1373)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2217)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6070)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:36)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                                                                               at com.morticia.android.firstmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Any professional insights would be greatly appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: your fragment inside activity_main.xml is not inflating. I this you full activity code above? And post your logcat too.

Comment: Thank you!  logcat is added

Comment: The logcat tells you exactly what to do. Just need to read it *completely*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

replace this code at your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.morticia.android.maptest_app"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

with

> Google Maps Android API
>    ENABLE

```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_MAP_API" />
```

or

> Google Maps Geolocation API ENABLE

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" 
android:value="YOUR_GEO_API"/>
```

Comment: This is progress as I am able to see an empty map with the Google logo in the bottom left corner of screen, but the map is blank.

Comment: map is blank because you have not activated the google map at console.

Comment: It's telling me there is an authorization error: '  Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                      Ensure that the following Android Key exists:'

Comment: enable the required map api at google console to view map

Comment: where you got that api key?

Comment: I did that and even generated a new key and replaced the old one.  It is enabled and I believe it's the only Google Maps API that offered

Comment: enable google map for android and google places api's. 
Then check whether this works or not

Comment: Finally nailed it.  That metadata correction that got it to work was: <meta-data> android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: for this anwer you need to activate the Google Maps Geolocation API
 ENABLE

Comment: @TJBlack31 these both will work depending upon the api you enabled. I answered what on basis of your logcat, you can check above the logcat you have posted.

Answer (score 34):

You should place

```
<application
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="<put your api KEY here"/>  
...
```

and **not** in other position like for example under:

```
<application
   <activity
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="<put your api KEY here"/>
```

Comment: Sir i have tried but not worked for me after build android file is override every-time tell me any another way?

Comment: I was trying for solutions for many days... this is the correct point where I made mistake (above <activity ....)..fixed now! thank you .

Answer (score 2):

I came across this but have been using EXPO, so the solution is a little diff: In a nutshell, you need to add the following 'config' for Maps to your package.json:

```
"android": {
      "package": "com.YOUR_PROJECT_NAME",
      "versionCode": 1.0,
      "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "CAMERA",
      ],
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "YOUR API KEY GOES HERE"
        }
      }
    },
```

See more info here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/

Comment: is app.json 
no package.json

Answer (score 2):

Add `meta-data` to `<application>` card in your `AndroidManifest` file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all above. Finally i got it fixed after pasting **meta-data** tag in the very next to application tag like this:

```
<application
    android:label="project_name"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="ZiNdASyDuQFXhEdK0TDkqF7WYnb2TfS6ugJZjNEU"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        ...
```

...

Comment: Yes, What worked for me was to place 
Api key the meta-data tag in application, not activity in androidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Replace android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" with **class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"** and try.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code

```
<application
    android:name=".util.SmartBus"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/googleMapKey"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```